# python logging not printing datetime and other format values

Tags: python, exception, logging, formatting

I'm trying to use the python logging module to create a `RotatingFileHandler` for my program.  My log handler logs output to the file: `/var/log/pdmd.log` and the basic functionality seems to work and log output as desired.

However, I'm trying to format my log string with this format:

```
"%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s"
```

But only the `message` portion of the exception is getting logged.  Here is my code to setup the logger:

```
#class variable declared at the beginning of the class declaration
log = logging.getLogger("PdmImportDaemon")

def logSetup(self):
    FORMAT = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)

    #logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    self.log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #by setting our logger to the DEBUG level (lowest level) we will include all other levels by default
    #setup the rotating file handler to automatically increment the log file name when the max size is reached
    self.log.addHandler( logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('/var/log/pdmd.log', mode='a', maxBytes=50000, backupCount=5) )
```

Now, when I run a method and make the program output to the log with the following code:

```
 def dirIterate( self ):
    try:
        raise Exception( "this is my exception, trying some cool output stuff here!")               
    except Exception, e:
        self.log.error( e )
        raise e
```

And the output in the `pdmd.log` file is just the exception text and nothing else.  For some reason, the formatting is not being respected; I expected:

```
 ERROR 2013-09-03 06:53:18,416 dirIterate 89 this is my exception, trying some cool output stuff here!
```

Any ideas as to why the formatting that I setup in my `logging.basicConfig` is not being respected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the format to the Handler too.

When you run `basicConfig()`, you are configuring a new Handler for the `root` Logger.
In this case your custom Handler is getting no format.

Replace

```
self.log.addHandler( logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('/var/log/pdmd.log', mode='a', maxBytes=50000, backupCount=5) )
```

with:

```
rothnd = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('/var/log/pdmd.log', mode='a', maxBytes=50000, backupCount=5)
rothnd.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(FORMAT))
self.log.addHandler(rothnd)
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and I get the following traceback:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdmd.py", line 195, in <module>
    prog = ProgramHandler()
  File "pdmd.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.logSetup()
  File "pdmd.py", line 55, in logSetup
    rothnd.format( FORMAT )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 723, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 464, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getMessage'
`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I fixed the example.

Comment: haha I figured out what the problem was and I was in the process of editing your post when you fixed it! thanks!